# django security: can an indirect view be called by a non-admin?

Tags: python, django, security, python-3.7

Say I have the following methods

```
@staff_member_required 
def foo(request):
    return say_secret_hello(request)

def says_secret_hello(request):
    #do secret stuff 
    return "hello
```

And in `urls.py`

```
path("/hello", foo)
```

As you can see, I have only exposed `foo` to my admins. From a security standpoint, is it ever possible for a **non-admin** to call `say_secret_hello()`?

Comment: Admin/Non admin is irrelevant, you've only provided a path to one of the views

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible for a regular user to call this function, you can also use the following syntax within the view :

```
if request.user.is_staff:
   #do some code
```

And within the template you can use the if statement :

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
Show some content 
{% endif %}
```